# Bug: HTML character references allowed in MathJax in preview but not on save

Tags: bug, mathjax

Here are some numeric character references outside MathJax (entered as `&#x266F; + &#x266D; = &#x266E;`):

> ♯ + ♭ = ♮

and inside MathJax (`$&#x266F; + &#x266D; = &#x266E;$`):

> $&#x266F; + &#x266D; = &#x266E;$

The latter renders properly in the preview, but is broken once I save. This makes [my suggestion for using curly quotes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3704/856) not work.

Comment: You should probably specify that your (bug) is to request that character references work, period. Right now a not-very-helpful fix to your not-quite-completely stated bug could potentially be fixing the preview so that it breaks there too... `:)`

Comment: Well, the fact that that the preview and the saved version are inconsistent is the bug. Making character references work everywhere would be a feature-request. :)

Comment: Oh, and I am surprised that mathjax does not have $\sharp$. (Edit: wait, it does!)

Comment: @Willie: There was $\sharp$ and $\#$ but the latter stopped working lately. (Edit: Oh, it works. Jerks.)

Answer (score 8):

You can use MathJax's `\unicode` extension to get the same effect.  E.g.,

```
$\unicode{x266F} + \unicode{x266D} = \unicode{x266E}$
```

should get the result you are looking for:

$$\unicode{x266F} + \unicode{x266D} = \unicode{x266E}$$